# show data from table on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new on Ruby and I am trying get data from table. so when read this

```
<%= puts @note.inspect %> I have this this result.

[#<Note id: 1, user_id: 1, note_type: 0, text: "Barev dzez", lat: 40.2290542420142, lng: 44.420879046875, deleted: false, created_at: "2012-04-26 14:10:05", updated_at: "2012-04-26 14:10:05">]
```

So when I call Note.text (for instance) I got nil result. So what should I write here to get data from array?
Thanks

Comment: did you try <%= @note.text %> ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@note` is an Array with one Note object. You need to get the element first. For example:

```
<%= @note.first.text %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are retrive record in an array so you need to call like this

```
      <%= puts @note.first.text %>
```

or

```
      <%= puts @note.last.text %>    if there is only one record
```

But you don't specify how you are retrive records..