# read data from table on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346140/show-data-from-table-on-ruby) question I have same problem too, but I wanted more.

```
%= puts @note.inspect %> I have this this result.

Note id: 1, user_id: 1, note_type: 0, text: "Hello", lat: 40.2290542420142, lng: 44.420879046875, deleted: false, created_at: "2012-04-26 14:10:05", updated_at: "2012-04-26 14:10:05">,

Note id: 2, user_id: 1, note_type: 0, text: "Bye", lat: nil, lng: nil, deleted: false, created_at: "2012-04-27 08:13:44", updated_at: "2012-04-27 08:13:44"
```

Also I did this `@note.first.text`, but here I could get only one value. But I want to get this result.

1. Hello world   70.2290542420142 74.420879046875
2. Bye

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `@note` is an array. So try something like:

```
<%- for n in @note %>
<%=  n.text %>
<%=  n.lat %>
<%=  n.lng %>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: It's fine bro, when i also call n.lat or n.lng my n.text disappear, why's that?